# What do the arguments passed inside the plt.plot() method mean?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scikit-learn

I was trying to plot a linear regression model in python using scikit learn and matplotlib. However, the code got confusing when I was plotting the data using plt.scatter() and plt.plot()

Here's my code which models the data using sklearn:-

```
from sklearn import linear_model
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
train_x = np.asanyarray(train[['ENGINESIZE']])
train_y = np.asanyarray(train[['CO2EMISSIONS']])
regr.fit (train_x, train_y)
# The coefficients
print ('Coefficients: ', regr.coef_)
print ('Intercept: ',regr.intercept_)
```

Here's my code which plots the linear regression model on a graph:-

```
plt.scatter(train.ENGINESIZE, train.CO2EMISSIONS,  color='blue')
plt.plot(train_x, regr.coef_[0][0]*train_x + regr.intercept_[0], '-y')
plt.xlabel("Engine size")
plt.ylabel("Emission")
```

I don't understand the arguments passed in `plt.scatter()` and `plt.plot()`. I noticed that when I remove the method `plt.plot()`, the line of best fit is not plotted on the graph.

Comment: ...have you looked at the documentation for those functions? That's usually the best place to look... You don't show your imports so I can only guess what you've imported as `plt` (or assigned to it), otherwise I'd link to the docs myself.

Comment: Please read [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot). `'-y'` means to plot a yellow line connecting the provided coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The plt library plots data. The first entry is the x data, the second the y data. Other inputs can be used to add colour, linewidth or marker type, as seen in [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html).

`plt.scatter` adds a scatter plot of your data. Guessing by the name of your variables I suspect:

```
plt.scatter(train.ENGINESIZE, train.CO2EMISSIONS,  color='blue')
```

Makes a scatter plot of all the engine sizes and their corresponding CO2 emmisions using blue markers.

The `plt.plot` draws a line. Guessing by the name of your variables I suspect

```
plt.plot(train_x, regr.coef_[0][0]*train_x + regr.intercept_[0], '-y')
```

Will plot the linear regression of your training data in yellow. `train_x` is the x data and `regr.coef_[0][0]*train_x + regr.intercept_[0]` the y data (it follows the formula y = a*x + b).